# Initial current surge

Tags: inrush-current

I designed a PCB that takes an input of 110Vdc and steps it down to 5Vdc for a microcontroller and a couple of ICs. At the input, I have a reverse protection diode, an inrush limiter circuit, and a filter:
[image]

Vin is connected to the DC-DC buck circuit to generate 5V for on-board ICs.

In normal operation, it draws about 60mA. But I noticed when I connected the PCB to the power supply, initially it drew a lot of current, and the current was even negative for about 125us:
[image]

I have a few questions and would very appreciate if someone could help me with them:

1. How can the current be negative?
2. How can I limit the magnitude of the current spikes at start-up?

Comment: Can you repeat the measurement with a ferrite bead in series with Q1 gate pin?

Comment: Your CLC filter is a very nice LC resonator.

Comment: Also, what is connected to Vin if anything, during the test?

Comment: D1 should be rated 200V at least.

Comment: Where and how are you measuring the current?

Comment: how are you generating the 110 Vdc?

Comment: @TimWilliams everything is on the PCB and I don't think I have the room to add the ferrite. Vin is connected to the buck converter.

Comment: @JonathanS. I swapped out the L with a 10R and had similar result

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica yes I missed that. I have replaced the part with the proper ratings.

Comment: @vir and jsotola, I have a DC power supply to power up the PCB. I use a clamp meter on the negative lead to measure the current.

Comment: Please show the buck converter, at least the components on the input side; and the DC supply: at least the output circuit, or model number if a commercial unit. Regarding room, your transistor is DPAK type, the lead of which can be lifted at least, or the trace can be cut and a bead added. As you haven't added layout pictures, I will assume such steps can be taken.